# How can I get a text inside a span without any id using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
<span onclick="selectText('email_ch_text')" id="email_ch_text">10005000986@ambiancewe.us</span>
```

How can I get using beautifoulsoup "10005000986@ambiancewe.us"

Comment: cant you use, .contents? refer to https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children or https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string

Comment: There *is* an id, it's email_ch_text.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
html_doc = "<span onclick=\"selectText('email_ch_text')\" id=\"email_ch_text\">10005000986@ambiancewe.us</span>"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.span.text)
```